# What kind of magnolias are in front of the White House?

Tags: identification, trees, magnolia

It looks to me that there are two magnolias in front of the White House.

What kind of magnolias are they?

[image]

The picture is actually a detail taken from [Donald Trump's twitter account today's background image](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump).

Comment: They might as well be Chinese Magnolias. I wonder if Trump paid tariffs for importing them ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely Magnolia soulangeana https://www.gardeningexpress.co.uk/s10622-magnolia-soulangeana-tulip-tree, but if it is, the flowers will eventually open out into saucer shapes. The other possibility is M. liliflora https://www.thespruce.com/growing-the-magnolia-iliflora-3269224 but this is less likely - it doesn't get as large as M. soulangeana.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Betty Magnolia]

[White House's History Magnolias](http://www.appalachianhistory.net/2011/05/the-presidents-the-magnolia-trees-and-the-museum.html)

The Betty is my guess and it is a guess!  Can't see the petal tips.  And they just took one down last year I guess planted by Andrew Jackson and that one was Magnolia grandiflora which is white and evergreen.  This will give you some ideas at least.

[5 great magnolias to consider](https://murul.net/magnolia/magnolia-tree-blooms.html)

Comment: What does 'the Betty' mean?

Comment: The scientific nomenclature is; Magnolia X Betty.  Seriously.  The sites about magnolia were very...vague.

Comment: I like soulangeana very much...like you said the other are large shrubs.  Thought I had addressed that one then got off into Magnolias of the White House histories...good grief! You would think we could get a plan of all the plants around that oh so important building!

Comment: So many newer varieties of Magnolia - but most of them don't get very big, maybe 10 feet or so. I'd have thought the one at the White House would be pretty old, so probably not a newer variety - can't tell the size from the pic in the question

Comment: The one that Andrew Jackson planted for his wife who died right after he got the office...was grandiflora.  Couple hundred years old?  They said they were removing a large part of it...whatever...these must be in the front  of White House?  Did you see the sheep?  Makes me so nostalgic.  Simpler times.

Comment: I just read yesterday they were removing M. grandiflora entirely - its completely rotten and the only thing holding it up were the ropes and supports.